# Running bash script in parallel?

Tags: bash

If I have a script, that works with input variables, (for example: ./test.sh var1 var2) could I run it in different terminals with different variables? Then it would work totally different files in totally different folders, but even the same script. Does it work?

Comment: Yes, totally, not a problem at all.

Comment: Check out `tmux` for running lots of things in your terminal with the ability to disconnect from them and reconnect to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely, obviously the more terminal connections you have doing this one script, the more resources you are going to use. I'm sure it will be okay but make sure to keep an eye on `top`.